# FFImageloading - check if image exists in cache?

Tags: xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

How can I check if an image exist in cache with FFImageLoading?

Comment: What would you like to achieve by check if an image exist in cache? Actually, `FFImageLoading` will do that check for you, and if not in cache it will download the image from the Internet.

Comment: I found my way around my original problem handling the `Error` event. A `FFImageLoading.DownloadAggregateException` is thrown even though the image exists in cache. I needed to display an image "resource not found" when image at the url ceased to exist.